# Updating Chart.js with JSON, cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I have a question about how to update a Chart.js chart via ajax and JSON. I've been trying and reading SO questions but I have reached a problem where CHart.js `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Here is my cshtml chart.js script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            // The type of chart we want to create
            type: 'line',

            // The data for our dataset
            data: {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                datasets: [{}]
            },
            // Configuration options go here
            options: {}
        });
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetChartData", "Plot")',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                    chart.data = result;
                    chart.update();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is my Controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetChartData()
 {
     List<String> datList = new List<string>();
     dataList.Add("1");
     dataList.Add("2");
     dataList.Add("3");
     dataList.Add("4");
     dataList.Add("5");
     string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dataList);
     return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

And here is a screenshot of the browser console:
[image]

In this picture, you can see the JSON response (not sure if that's the problem) and the Chart.js error.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like the response you get back is a string right? Also data seems to need labels too? Can you try:
chart.data = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
  JSON.parse(result)
}

Comment: @dbramwell Just tried it, same problem

Comment: Just edited my comment

Comment: It's giving me an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you're giving it the data in the wrong format. Ignoring the ajax request for now, you need to do something along the lines of:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            // The type of chart we want to create
            type: 'line',

            // The data for our dataset
            data: {
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
                datasets: [{}]
            },
            // Configuration options go here
            options: {}
        });
        $("button").click(function () {
            chart.data.datasets = [{data: [1,2,3,4,5]}]
            chart.update()
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>button</button>
<canvas id="myChart" >
```

The response you get from the request is a string, so you actually need to do:

```
chart.data.datasets = [{data: JSON.parse(response)}]
```

Comment: You're a gem! This worked perfectly, I wish I could give you more than 1 upvote